# A problem in calculus(an inequality regarding limits) to show f(x) < (1 +1/e).

Tags: calculus, limits

f : R → R is a function such that f(1) = 1 and f'(x) = $e^{−xf(x)}$ holds for all x∈R.
P.T. $lim_{x→∞}$ f(x) < (1 +1/e).

I encountered this problem in a textbook of calculus. Now what I immediately thought of having such a function which satisfies the condition f'(x)=$e^{−xf(x)}$ .I need to identify the function and then prove the inequality of the limit.
Kindly shower some help....thank you.

And yes... This is not a homework problem and I have mentioned my thought process.

Comment: It would be helpful to have more details about the source (book title, page #, etc)

Comment: Show $f'(x)\lt e^{-x}$

Comment: Just out of curiosity: would you mind to post your working definition of "thought process"? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $f$ is strictly increasing over $\mathbb{R}$ because the inequality

$$f'(x)=e^{-xf(x)}>0$$

holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

It follows that for $x\geq 1$,

\begin{align*}
f(x) &\geq f(1)=1\\
xf(x) &\geq x\\
-xf(x) &\leq-x\\
e^{-xf(x)}&\leq e^{-x}
\end{align*}

so $f'(x)\leq e^{-x}$ for $x\geq 1$.

Basic integral inequalities and two applications of $\text{FTC}2$ then establish that

\begin{align*}
f(x)-1 &= f(x)-f(1)\\
&= \int_{1}^{x}f'(t)\text{ }dt\\
&\leq \int_{1}^{x}e^{-t}\text{ }dt\\
&=e^{-1}-e^{-x}
\end{align*}

so $f(x)\leq 1+\frac{1}{e}-e^{-x}\leq 1+\frac{1}{e}$. This means that $f$ is eventually monotonically increasing and is bounded above by $1+\frac{1}{e}$, so it must have a limit. Denoting the limit by $L$, we deduce that

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\leq \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{e}-e^{-x}\right)=1+\frac{1}{e}$$

I'm not sure how to prove that $L\neq 1+\frac{1}{e}$. Hope this still helps!